# Files (Nautilus) icons not appearing with Numix Square icon theme on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Unity desktop

Tags: unity, nautilus, icons

I'm using Unity 7 on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I've installed and set the [Numix Square](https://github.com/numixproject/numix-icon-theme-square) icon theme and restarted Unity. Nautilus seems to still show the default empty file icon for all files and folders. It does show image thumbnails, however. Changed icons with Unity Tweak Tool.

Answer (score 2):

I did not have any icon themes installed with folder and file icons so it fell back to the default empty file icon from the GNOME system theme.

Both [Numix Square](https://github.com/numixproject/numix-icon-theme-square) and [Numix Circle](https://github.com/numixproject/numix-icon-theme-circle) do not have built-in system icons or file/folder icons but instead require the [Numix](https://github.com/numixproject/numix-icon-theme) icon theme to be installed. This fixed my particular problem!